# Proving an infinite product of analytic functions is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{z}\sin(\frac{z}{n})$ is well-defined and analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$? Should I begin by rewriting $\frac{n}{z}\sin(\frac{z}{n})$ using the Euler infinite product or is there an approach that doesn't require having a double infinite product?

Answer (score 1):

Write $H(U)$ for the set of functions which are analytic on $U$, with $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ open,

> *Theorem: Let $f_n\in H(U)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that no $f_n$ is identically zero in any component of $U$ and that
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |1-f_n(z)|$$
> converges uniformly on compact subsets of $U$. Then the product
> $$ f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$$
> converges uniformyl on compact subsets of $U$. In particular, $f\in H(U)$.*

For a proof, see Theorem 15.6 in the third edition of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

So, we'll be done if we can show that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| 1-\frac{n}{z}\sin\left(\frac{z}{n}\right)\right|
$$
converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ (note that each factor is actually entire, as it can be analytically extended to $z=0$).

Thus, it suffices to study the growth rate of $\left |1-\frac{\sin(w)}{w}\right|$. Take the Taylor expansion about $0$ to control this.

Comment: Thank you! Expanding out of the Taylor expansion you mention in your last line, I'm having trouble controlling the growth rate of $|1-\frac{\sin(w)}{w}| = |-\frac{w^2}{3!} + \frac{w^4}{5!} - ...|$. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Nina I'm sorry, the argument I had in mind doesn't quite work, and now I'm not sure how to bound $1-\frac{\sin(w)}{w}$. I'll keep thinking about it, apologies for the mix up!